# Angular2, How to set width in table each td in grid View

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I need to fix width in "table->thead->td" in grid view.But I am getting head 
   elements from array. I don't know how to set each tr when i using from array.

This is my Table column. I need to set width each tr. Anyone Please Help 
   me????

```
 private channelsListColumnsForOwner: Array<any> = [
{ title: 'Name', name: 'name', sort:'asc'},
{ title: 'Owner', name: 'customer.name', sort:'asc'},
{ title: 'Description', name: 'description',sort:'asc'},
{ title: 'Controlled Channel', name: 'isControlled',sort:'asc'},
{ title: 'Active', name: 'isActive',sort:'asc' },
{ title: 'Subscribers', name: 'name',sort:'asc'},
{ title: 'Action' }
];
```

Comment: what exactly do you want? to populate your header row with values from this array? what is this "set width"? is this a typo?

Comment: Hi..I need to set "width" in thead->td for table alignment. But i fetch the above method. So that I don't know how to set that. Plz??

Answer (score 2):

// Html code

```
      <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let p of channelsListColumnsForOwner">
        <td [style.width.px]="xx" *ngIf="p.title">{{p.title}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="p.name">{{p.name}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="p.sort">{{p.sort}}</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
```